# testing react custom hook that has fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have written a simple custom hook. All it does does it to call an api with fetch and save the data in a state and return the state so that the components can use it.

Below is the code for `useTodos.js`

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function useTodos() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([{ a: 1 }]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setTodos(data));
  }, []);

  return todos;
}
```

Below is the code for `useTodos.test.js`

```
import { waitFor, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useTodos } from "./useTodos";

test("fetch should return data", async () => {
  const data = renderHook(() => useTodos());
  console.log(data.result.current);
  await waitFor(() => {
    console.log(data.result.current);
  });
});
```

Output I get for the console.log :

```
  console.log
      [ { a: 1 } ]   
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/useTodos.test.js:6:11)    
    console.log
      [ { a: 1 } ]    
      at src/useTodos.test.js:8:13
```

My understanding was that the state in the waitFor callback should display the result after calling the API, but I get the initialState `[ { a: 1 } ]` which I had set in `useState`.

How do I correct this?

Comment: What exactly do you think [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) is waiting for? The first time the callback is called, _no error gets thrown_. Also you probably don't want your low-level tests waiting for actual network requests.

Comment: since fetch is async, I thought we should use `waitFor`.
Now I am also confused why did not in both the cases, with and without using `waitFor`?

Comment: You will need to use waitFor, but you need to give it something to _actually wait for_; something that initially fails and should succeed once the hook has worked. Right now you're just logging, which is pointless and tells it nothing.

Comment: Is there a way I could get the actual API call result in my test case instead of getting `[ { a: 1 } ]`?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you don't have an assertion statement(`expect()`) in your `waitFor` callback. In a `waitFor` callback there has to be at least one assertion that is waiting for a promise to get resolved or rejected.

In your case your code should look like:

```
import { waitFor, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useTodos } from "./useTodos";

test("fetch should return data", async () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useTodos());
  expect(result.current).toEqual([{ a: 1 }]) // your hook got executed and has the initial state of todos
  await waitFor(() => {
    // waiting to get resolve the current promise
    expect(result.current).toEqual([...]) // add your expected value after the todo state gots updated
  });
});
```

In the `waitFor` callback we are waiting that the promise of `result.current` gets resolved. In your case `results.current` is your todos list. With the code line `expect(result.current)` we are waiting for an update of the todos list. This update happens because your `useEffect` hook gets executed and you update your todos list state with the `setTodos` function. This state update triggers a re-rendering of your custom hook and returns the new todo list, which we are waiting for.

Hint:
You should mock your fetch request instead of doing a real fetch request against "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com" whenever you run your tests. Mocking fetch requests has a lot of advantages for example it makes test execution faster, is more reliable and you don't bother a real api with your test executions :D!

Comment: This did not work. I can mock API with MSW. I am just trying to do it by using jest and RTL alone.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly does not work? Is there an error message, which you can share with us? I tested your custom hook with my test implementation and it works like expected.